# How to add a date field in system.xml?

Tags: magento-1.7, date, system.xml

How can I create a date field by using system.xml?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you add the following in your system.xml

```
<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<frontend_model>namespace_module/adminhtml_system_config_date</frontend_model>
```

Then create the following file:

app/code/[codePool]/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Date.php

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date();
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

        $data = array(
            'name'      => $element->getName(),
            'html_id'   => $element->getId(),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        );
        $date->setData($data);
        $date->setValue($element->getValue(), $format);
        $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));
        $date->setForm($element->getForm());

        return $date->getElementHtml();
    }
}
```

This is assuming that you already have the blocks setup for this module in the config.xml

Comment: @Sukeshini, For blocks in the config.xml you need to add <blocks>
 <module>
  <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
 </module>
</blocks>

Comment: Please note that the date will be saved in the locale set by your admin. This can cause problems. For example: the dutch date format is dd-MM-YYYY. This will be saved as a string in your database in this format. Other processes that depend on this date might not work properly. For example: when generating a PDF, the locale returned by Magento is en_US, even if the admin is set to something different. This can cause unforeseen results.